# From List of Dictionary To Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have some problem with my function.

I do an SQL Query to obtain a list that have some dictionary with only a key/value element.
This is a sample of my output:

```
myDictList = [{'id': 55, 'sigla': 'SNG'}, {'id': 62, 'sigla': 'TRP'}, 
 {'id': 71, 'sigla': 'PCNIM'},  {'id': 72, 'sigla': 'pc2ni'}, 
 {'id': 73, 'sigla': 'ccas'}, {'id': 74, 'sigla': 'ased1'}, 
 {'id': 75, 'sigla': '131s'}, {'id': 76, 'sigla': 'r888'}, 
 {'id': 56, 'sigla': 'DBL'}]
```

The `id` are unique (for SQL constraint).

I've build a list of `id` in that way

```
r_id_list = list(rid['id'] for rid in roomList)
```

Now, i would build a dict. like that from `myDictList`:

```
{55:'SNG',62:'TRP',71:'PCNIM'.... and so on}
```

More over, i want to avoid part of code like that:

```
finalDict = {}
for element in myDictList:
    finalDict.update({element['id']:element['sigla']})
```

I want to do that for some reasons:

- I don't want to do two separate query to obtain some data that i can retrive with one
- I don't want to iterate to every list element for retrive `sigla` value from `r_id_list` element

Some suggestion for a compact code that will not include a `for` cycle inside a `for` cycle, and increase the complexity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
finalDict = dict([(k['id'], k['sigla']) for k in myDictList])
```

**EDIT1**
As comment mentioned, it will be a better way to do.

```
finalDict = dict(((k['id'], k['sigla']) for k in myDictList))
```

**EDIT2**

```
finalDict = dict((k['id'], k['sigla']) for k in myDictList)
```

Comment: Remove the outer square brackets and it's perfect.

Comment: Thank you, that works. When i've tried i do something like that, but without `[(k['id'], k['sigla'])` (i do something like `k['id']:k['sigla']`). Now i got the point.

Comment: @lucemia - I meant "remove", not "replace with round brackets".

Comment: In recent Python you can do `{k['id']:k['sigla'] for k in myDictList}`

Comment: Interesting blog post on performance merits of using dict comprehension over `dict()` constructor: http://blog.doughellmann.com/2012/11/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict.html

Answer (score 3):

Use dict() constructor with generator expression:

```
finalDict = dict((elem['id'], elem['sigla']) for elem in myDictList)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
finaldict = {k['id']: k['sigla'] for k in myDictList}
```

if you're on a current version of Python. Dictionary comprehensions have been introduced in Python 3 and backported to Python 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> myDictList = [{'id': 55, 'sigla': 'SNG'}, {'id': 62, 'sigla': 'TRP'},
...  {'id': 71, 'sigla': 'PCNIM'},  {'id': 72, 'sigla': 'pc2ni'},
...  {'id': 73, 'sigla': 'ccas'}, {'id': 74, 'sigla': 'ased1'},
...  {'id': 75, 'sigla': '131s'}, {'id': 76, 'sigla': 'r888'},
...  {'id': 56, 'sigla': 'DBL'}]
>>> {k['id']: k['sigla'] for k in myDictList}
{71: 'PCNIM', 72: 'pc2ni', 73: 'ccas', 74: 'ased1', 75: '131s', 76: 'r888', 55:'SNG', 56: 'DBL', 62: 'TRP'}
```

Comment: With python 2.7 that didn't work. I've tried. That's the reason of my question.

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.7.2. Did you use exactly the code I'm using?

Comment: Sorry, i've lied to you: `>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.4.3 (#1, Feb  3 2007, 20:05:13)
[GCC 4.1.1 (Gentoo 4.1.1-r3)]`

Comment: I agree with you, but i can't take that kind of decision

Answer (score 1):

Consider taking a step back here and looking outside the narrow focus of the question. You say "I do an SQL Query to obtain a list that have some dictionary". What are you using to do the SQL query?

By default Python database drivers return a `tuple` for each row rather than `dict`, so you presumably have some other code which is converting those tuples into a `dict` before you want to convert them back again. Your best bet would be to just do a query that returns tuples and construct your dict directly from that:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id, sigla FROM sometable')
myDict = dict(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: I have a "pillow" library that we had wrote where i work, and for us obtain a dict is the best way. I can't rewrite that method because is used in a wide area. I can't neither overload it, but thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
res_dict = {}
for i in myDictList:
    res_dict[i['id']] = i['sigla']
```

Comment: List/dict comprehensions are better as its more efficient, concise and yet more pythoinic

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out the best way to build your final dictionary is using a *generator expression* like:

```
finalDict = dict((d['id'], d['sigla']) for d in myDictList)
```

And if you still need an iterable over your ids you can have that just calling `finalDict.keys()`.